# How to dynamically bind number to enum

Tags: c#, enums

here is how we define number to enum:

```
enum Color
{
    Red = 1,
    Green = 2,
    Blue = 3
}
```

By this, the number value is const.

How about I want to assign it in runtime dynamically? or change it in code? and change it becomes like this:

```
enum Color
{
    Red = 4,
    Green = 8,
    Blue = 9
}
```

I there a method like

```
Enum.BindNumber(Color.Red, 4);
```

---

**Solution:**

After reading the answers/information below, I have written a custom class to resolve this problem:

```
public enum SectionName
{
    UnknownSection,
    SectionA,
    SectionB,
    SectionC,
    SectionD
}

public class Section
{
    Dictionary<SectionName, int> dic = new Dictionary<SectionName, int>();

    public int SectionA { get { return dic[SectionName.SectionA]; } }
    public int SectionB { get { return dic[SectionName.SectionB]; } }
    public int SectionC { get { return dic[SectionName.SectionC]; } }
    public int SectionD { get { return dic[SectionName.SectionD]; } }

    public int this[SectionName sn]
    {
        get
        {
            if (dic.ContainsKey(sn))
                return dic[sn];
            return 0;
        }
        set
        {
            dic[sn] = value;
        }
    }

    public SectionName this[int num]
    {
        get
        {
            foreach(var kv in dic)
            {
                if (kv.Value == num)
                    return kv.Key;
            }
            return SecionName.UnknownSection;
        }
        set
        {
            dic[value] = num;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update: The scenario behind**

I would like to respond to a few feedbacks and question below where I was asked that why do I need to do this Enum>>Number binding? I'll explain my scenario below:

You know guys, for me changing database structure is a little bit headache in long run. I somehow feel that changing code is much more easier than changing database structure.

If you chanage the database stucture, it will have earthquake destructing equivalent effect on overall of the coding part. But you can always change code without changing database.

So, in the long run, the database has to be well designed in the form of it enable flexible and ability of adaption of changes and sustainable for program version evolution.

In my current new project.. it is custom web cms project. This is the very first attempt, I build the website with only 1 table. Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `key` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` mediumtext,
  `seq` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Table structure

```
------------------------------------
Columns   | Data Type              |
------------------------------------
id        | int (auto-increment)   |
parent_id | int                    |
key       | varchar                |
data      | mediumtext             |
seq       | int                    |
status    | int                    |
------------------------------------
```

The very first item in the database will be the domain item, something like this:

1st Item

```
id = 1 <auto-generate> first item
parent_id = 0 (this is the first item, definitely no parent
key = 'mydomainname.com'
data = null (not important at this stage)
seq = null (not important at this stage)
status = null (not important at this stage)
```

There are many predefined SECTIONS in the website, for example:

- Front Page Slider
- Web Editors (user)
- Footer Blocks
- Category1
- Category2
- etc....

Each of these section will be define in the **Enum**

```
Section            | Enum
-------------------------------------
Front Page Slider  | FrontPageSlider
Web Editors (user) | UserList
Footer Blocks      | FooterBlock
Category1          | Category1
Category2          | Category2
```

I store all the infromation using "key"<>"data" (parent<>child) matching methods and stored it in the database.

**For example: Storing the slider data**

First, create the Slider Parent Item

```
id = 2 <auto-generate> 2nd item
parent_id = 1 (refers to 1st item)
key = 'FrontPageSlider'
data = null (not important at this stage)
seq = null (not important at this stage)
status = null (not important at this stage)
```

Now, is the slides data

1st slide

```
id = 3 <auto-generate> 3rd item
parent_id = 2 (refers to 2nd item)
key = 'my_first_photo.jpg'
data = null (not important at this stage)
seq = 1 
status = 1
```

2nd slide

```
id = 4 <auto-generate>
parent_id = 2 (refers to 2nd item)
key = 'dog_cat_running.jpg'
data = null (not important at this stage)
seq = 1 
status = 1
```

**Another Example: Storing User Editor's Data**

Create User Parent Item

```
id = 5 <auto-generate>
parent_id = 1 
key = 'UserList'
data = null (not important at this stage)
seq = null (not important at this stage)
status = null (not important at this stage)
```

1st User:

```
id = 6 <auto-generate>
parent_id = 5
key = 'adam'
data = 'pwd=fa23f....2f283|salt=faff...awefw|fullname=Adam Smith
seq = null (not important at this stage)
status = 1
```

2nd User:

```
id = 7 <auto-generate>
parent_id = 5
key = 'jasmine'
data = 'pwd=0x0a2f....2f3|salt=0xfxff...afb|fullname=Jasmine Irene
seq = null (not important at this stage)
status = 1
```

Ok, now you get how the data is linked between each other.

The fixed sections will be define in the coding as Enum but the id is auto-generated in the database as the 2nd level parent. I need to bind the number(auto-incremented id) from database to Enum, so that I can get the parent item from database and sub-subsequently get the child items.

As some of you have said, this is crazy attempt. Yes, I totally agree with you guys this crazy. I'm not sure how you feel about it, but I personally feel that this quite an awesome attempt to use just 1 table for everything :)

Comment: maybe [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.enumbuilder.aspx)  will help you, try and look in the Examples sections

Comment: Makes me wonder, why do you need to reassign the values? (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @caramiriel this number is ID autoincrement from database which created or loaded on runtime. Each product will have same fixed color range, but differrent properties under each color section. For example, paper.Color.Red.Supplier = "ABC Company", then, MetalBox.Color.Red.Supplier = "XYZ Company"

Comment: @Caramiriel besides, this is multiple sites hosted in the same database. Website A (for client A), website B (for client b), each color range will have differrent properties between different websites. therefore the id number is dynamically assigned

Comment: @Caramiriel Hi, i have made a more complete explanation above. You can have a look on it :)

Comment: I would suggest on having a table for the sections, and a table for articles (?). If the properties of the articles happen to be dynamic, you can also choose to add an `article_properties` table. Either way the value of the color would be 'red'. I wouldn't hard code it in the application, as you don't want to change/redeploy the application if you want to add something (such as colors, sections, items, etc...).

Comment: @Caramiriel Hi, thanks for you idea.

Comment: @Caramiriel Yes, there will have dynamic articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but as a workaround, you can consider a `Dictionary`:

```
var colorsDict = new Dictionary<Color, int>() {
   {Color.Red, 4}, {Color.Green, 8}, {Color.Blue, 9}
};
```

You can change it dynamically whenever you want.

However, you obviously can't then cast a number to an enum and expect to get a correct result:

```
(Color)8 // probably not green
```

Even if the language does support the above, doing so is still can be problematic when the values can change. You might accidentally change something and everything breaks.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I written a custom class based on your idea. I updated my question to show the custom class.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible, you can think of enum values as constants and the names just as "placeholders" to make the code more readable. Behind the scenes the enum is just a struct, which has a `value__` field (the numeric value) and several constants for the named values. As they are constants, you cannot modify them at runtime.

```
.class private auto ansi sealed Color extends [mscorlib]System.Enum
{
  .field public specialname rtspecialname int32 value__
  .field public static literal valuetype Color Red = int32(0x00000001)
  .field public static literal valuetype Color Green = int32(0x00000002)
  .field public static literal valuetype Color Blue= int32(0x00000003)
}
```

Comment: then I will have to do some workaround, like creating a custom class. I have updated my question for doing the custom class.

Comment: Not a workaround. Constants called constant, because they are constant. You cant write a workaround to change a constant - then its not longer a constant. Your "workaround" looks a little over engineered. Why you dont use simply a dict?

Comment: @user6537157 dict is just one way binding, I need 2 ways binding

Answer (score 1):

I reworte your wrapper.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This class wrapps any enum and make values changeable.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Struct to be wrapped</typeparam>
    public class ChangeableEnum<T> where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        // This dict contains all values of enum
        IDictionary<T, int> _dict;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor intializes with the given enum (as generic-class-type)
        /// </summary>
        public ChangeableEnum()
        {
            _dict = new Dictionary<T, int>();

            // iterate over each value and get value
            foreach (T obj in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
                _dict.Add(obj, Convert.ToInt32(obj));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get or set a value of enum.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">Enum-type to get or set</param>
        /// <returns>Value of given enum-type.</returns>
        public int this[T obj]
        {
            get { return _dict[obj]; }
            set { _dict[obj] = value; }
        }
    }
```

This code is untested and may have some bugs.

How to use for color-enum:

```
    public enum Color
    {
        Red = 4,
        Green = 8
    }
```

And in a method

```
ChangeableEnum<Color> test = new ChangeableEnum<Color>();

// get
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(test[Color.Red]);

// set
test[Color.Red] = 5436;

// get again
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(test[Color.Red]);
```

But I think, that you use enums in a wrong context.

Comment: I'm doing something crazy stuff ;) I'm actually doing a custom web cms with only 1 table in database :) I have updated my question to explain this

Comment: Your class makes the wrapper even more dynamic. another cool attempt. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is all madness. But I like a bit of madness once in a while...

```
public struct Colour
{
    private static Dictionary<string, int> _bindings = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    private string _key { get; set; }

    public static Colour Red => new Colour(nameof(Red));
    public static Colour Green => new Colour(nameof(Green));
    public static Colour Blue => new Colour(nameof(Blue));

    private Colour(string colour)
    {
        _key = colour;
    }

    public static void BindNumber(Colour colour, int value)
    {
        _bindings[colour._key] = value;
    }

    public static explicit operator int (Colour colour)
    {
        return _bindings.TryGetValue(colour._key, out var value) ? value : throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(colour));
    }

    public static implicit operator string (Colour colour)
    {
        return colour.ToString();
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Colour colour1, Colour colour2)
    {
        return colour1._key == colour2._key;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Colour colour1, Colour colour2)
    {
        return colour1._key != colour2._key;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Colour colour, int value)
    {
        return (int)colour == value;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Colour colour, int value)
    {
        return (int)colour != value;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return ((Colour)obj)._key == _key;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _key.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _key;
    }
}
```

And to use this crazy class:

```
Colour.BindNumber(Colour.Red, 3);
Colour.BindNumber(Colour.Blue, 6);
Colour.BindNumber(Colour.Green, 7);

var redTest = Colour.Red;
var greenTest = Colour.Green;
var blueTest = Colour.Blue;

Console.WriteLine(redTest); //Red
Console.WriteLine((int)redTest); //3

Console.WriteLine(greenTest); //Green
Console.WriteLine((int)greenTest); //7

Console.WriteLine(blueTest); //Blue
Console.WriteLine((int)blueTest); //6

var red1 = Colour.Red;
var red2 = Colour.Red;
var green1 = Colour.Green;

Console.WriteLine(red1 == red2); //True
Console.WriteLine(Colour.Red == Colour.Red); //True
Console.WriteLine(red1 == green1); //False
Console.WriteLine(red1 == 3); //True
Console.WriteLine(red1 == 5); //False
```

Caveats:

- This whole idea is a bit of a brain fart. I don't recommend you use it.
- This code is most definitely not thread safe!
- I haven't thought about the consequences beyond solving your immediate problem. Perhaps you should?

Enjoy!

Comment: Crazy means doing something out of ordinary practice. All the mind blown inventions, discoveries and creativity around the world came from crazy thoughts. I like how you call it "crazy" :) and I have another interpretation, I call it "The Art of Programming" :)  . Thanks for your another crazy attempt

Comment: I have update my question to explain the scenario behind this story. and I totally agree with you that this is a crazy attempt... wu hah hah ha (evil laugh) :)